# Is this function continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Suppose that $f: (0,1] → \mathbb{R}$ is such that  $\lim \limits_{x \to a^-}f(x) =f(a)$ for all $a∈(0,1]$. Is $f$ continuous on $(0,1]$?

I don't really know how to solve this question. I suspect that it is continuous but not sure how to do rigorous proof. I suspect that you can show that $f(a+\epsilon)$ is continuous from the left and thus the limit of $f(a)$ is continuous am I on the right track

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I realized I left something out from the proof

Comment: @MikeEarnest Did you miss that it's $x \to a^-$ rather than $x \to a$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I was commenting on an old edit, so I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all you have is that the function is continuous from the left.  For example,
consider $$f(x) = \cases{0 & if $x \le 1/2$\cr 1 & if $x > 1/2$}$$
which satisfies the condition, but is not continuous.

Comment: But since it is for all values of a in (0,1] if you take a to be a point just after 1/2 the limit from the left does not exist, violating the condition

Comment: Any point "just after" $1/2$ is still strictly greater than $1/2$, making the limit from the left $1$.

Comment: Ahh I see now thank you